# How to report a value back to the driver from mapper?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

In my hadoop application I need to report a value (let's time when mapper is done processing) back to the driver program. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You maybe able to get such information by looking at the different reports generated by Hadoop for any mapreduce job.

In general, however, you can pass information back to the driver using counters. In your mapper you can do something like:

```
context.getCounter("records", "last_seen").setValue(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

and then read it from the driver as:

```
job.getCounters().getGroup("records").findCounter("last_seen").getValue();
```

Comment: Where exactly in the driver I can retrieve it? I'd like to retrieve it when the mappers are done. Where should I put in the driver?

Comment: beside, let's say each mapper set a different value for the COUNTER. How can I get the maximum value?

Comment: Somewhere after job.waitForCompletion(true);

Comment: what if I want to report a String value instead of a long value?